# Apache camel rabbitmq endpoint thread name not editable

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

We are using camel rabbitmq endpoints for consuming and working on messages from rabbitmq. 
We are not able to change thread name of camel rabbit based consumers, so that we are able to distinguish between multiple threads while debugging or checking thread dumps. 
Currently the thread name defaults to "RabbitMQConsumer". 
How can we change this?

I checked camel-rabbitmq endpoint class in github and found

```
protected ExecutorService createExecutor() {
        if (getCamelContext() != null) {
            return getCamelContext().getExecutorServiceManager().newFixedThreadPool(this, "RabbitMQConsumer", getThreadPoolSize());
        } else {
            return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(getThreadPoolSize());
        }
    }
```

Comment: The thread name should use a counter as well like #2 #3 etc to make them unique. Don't you see that, and can you post some logs as proof - and make sure your logger don't clip the thread name? And what version of Camel do you use

Comment: Yes Claus, it does show the counter. like this [Camel (camel-1) thread #211 - RabbitMQConsumer].  But the name of route is same for all. i.e. "RabbitMQConsumer". Whereas while using "seda" the behaviour is different. the logs for seda shows some route  details from which we are able to distinguish the threads.

Comment: And version we are using is 2.23.0

Comment: Ah okay we can make it more similar to seda, you are welcome to log a JIRA and provide a PR. All you need to do is to replace that with `endpoint.getEndpointUri()` like seda does.

Comment: Ok Will do. Thanks @ClausIbsen

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13685